# Matplotlib. Align subplot with Bbox

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a grid of 6 subplots. The last subplot is square. I need to move it to the left so that its left y-axis is perfectly aligned with the y-axis of the plot above it. I know I can get and set the Bbox parameters, but I can't move it in the right direction. Whether I increase or decrease x1 and x2, it always seems to move to the right.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3)
fig.tight_layout(pad=3.0)
fig.set_figwidth(30)
fig.set_figheight(15)

axs[1, 2].set_aspect('equal')

print(axs[1, 2].get_position())
```

The print command returns:

```
Bbox(x0=0.7620938740079364, y0=0.16765873015873023, x1=0.8925502232142856, y1=0.4285714285714286)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.get_position()` method indeed returns the bounding box of given axes. The idea is to use the `Bbox` of the axes right above the square axes in order to align them with it. This can be done with:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# the figure size can be set directly from here
# I used smaller figure size than in your example for visibility
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(15, 7))
fig.tight_layout(pad=3.0)

axs[1, 2].set_aspect('equal')

# extract positions of square and above axes
p02 = axs[0, 2].get_position()
p12 = axs[1, 2].get_position()

# make square axes with left position taken from above axes, and set position
p12 = [p02.x0, p12.y0, p12.width, p12.height]
axs[1, 2].set_position(p12)

plt.show()
```

Which results in:

[image: left-align axes matplotlib subplot]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried. You can play around the position numbers based on your output.

```
ax[6].set_position([0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2])
```

You can use this URL for reference to deep dive into the subject.

[Customizing Figure Layouts Using GridSpec and Other Functions](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html)

Comment: I know that's the function I should use, but I don't understand how I should calibrate the numbers, they don't make intuitive sense to me. I tried to google but didn't find clarity. Also, the link you posted does not seem to mention Bbox.